# How to view JS code loaded with AJAX in browser?

Tags: ajax, firefox, browser, reload

I have a JSP page, where some parts of the pages are loaded from the backend using AJAX. For example, when I first open the page, the URL is http://www.made-up-domain-name-because-of-stack-overflow-restrictions.com/listUsers.do. The page contains an "add user" button, which loads HTML content (containing a form etc.) from the backend to the div-element with id "addArea". The URL stays the same the whole time (naturally), as the request is done in the background.

The problem I have is that the content loaded using AJAX is not completely viewable with any means.

Using Firefox I can see the new HTML with the Firebug add-on and "Inspect element", but the content within the script-tags is not visible that way (also not in the "Script" tab in Firebug - only the originally loaded scripts appear there). If I use "View page source" in FF a page reload is executed and I don't see the newly generated content (I only see the content of page http://www.made-up-domain-name-because-of-stack-overflow-restrictions.com/listUsers.do as it was when first loaded).

With Chrome I have the same problem as with Firefox.

Using IE I see only the original source.

Of course I can work around this by adding debugging mechanisms to the JS code and working half-blind, or moving parts of the JS code to external files etc., but if by any means possible, I would prefer to just view the code loaded using AJAX. Any suggestions, perhaps using some add-on?

**Update:** There is a better way: see the accepted answer for this question: [How to debug dynamically loaded javascript(with jquery) in the browser's debugger itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9092125/how-to-debug-dynamically-loaded-javascriptwith-jquery-in-the-browsers-debugge/9092205#9092205)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [JavaScript Deobfuscator extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/addon/javascript-deobfuscator/) for that. It can show you what scripts are compiled/executed on a webpage - including the ones that were loaded dynamically.

Comment: Link is broken and searching add-ons did not turn up comparable results.

Comment: @AufgeschissenerKunde: Yes, that extension was possible with Mozilla’s original extension model. Once Mozilla switched to Chrome’s limited extension model, the extension could no longer be provided.