# Chrome Console: VM

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

When executing a script directly in the console in Chrome, I saw this:

[image]

Does anyone know what's the meaning of VM117:2

What does VM stand for ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17367560/chrome-development-tool-vm-file-from-javascript

Comment: is there a way to remove it/disable printing it? often totally useless for me. i just want to copy links or data from the console, mostly logged XHRs.

Comment: @computingfreak This is a shot in the dark since the comment thread is so old, but have you managed to figure out how to disable it? I'm getting it printed 20+ times for every page load and it's driving me crazy!

Comment: @MRB I found a solution, added as an answer to this question - please check at https://stackoverflow.com/a/67026569/1818089

Comment: @MRB not sure whether my answer would be kept, please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36009071/how-to-omit-file-line-number-with-console-log, and acknowledge somehow.

Comment: @computingfreak I am so appreciative that you responded! I was more so wondering if you had figured out how to disable the debugger from logging. My debugger is running 20+ times in a row and filling the console w/ print statements. More explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67024539/how-to-stop-chrome-devtools-debugger-from-logging-repeatedly-in-the-console

Answer (score 58, accepted):

It is abbreviation of the phrase Virtual Machine.
In the Chrome JavaScript engine (called V8) each script has its own script ID.

Sometimes V8 has no information about the file name of a script, for example in the case of an `eval`. So devtools uses the text "VM" concatenated with the script ID as a title for these scripts.

Some sites may fetch many pieces of JavaScript code via XHR and `eval` it. If a developer wants to see the actual script name for these scripts they can use [sourceURL](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/sourcemappingurl-and-sourceurl-syntax-changed). DevTools parses and uses it for titles, mapping etc.

Comment: Is there a reference on this?

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to @MRB,

I revisited this problem, and found the solution today,
thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/63221101/1818089

```
queueMicrotask (console.log.bind (console, "Look! No source file info..."));
```

It will group similar elements, so make sure you add a unique identifier to each log line to be able to see all data.

[image]

Demonstrated in the following example.

Instead of

```
data = ["Apple","Mango","Grapes"];
for(i=0;i<10;i++){
    queueMicrotask (console.log.bind (console, " info..."+i));
}
```

use

```
data = ["Apple","Mango","Grapes"];
for(i=0;i<data.length;i++){
    queueMicrotask (console.log.bind (console, " info..."+i));
}
```

A better way would be to make a console.print function that does so and call it instead of console.log as pointed out in https://stackoverflow.com/a/64444083/1818089

```
// console.print: console.log without filename/line number
console.print = function (...args) {
    queueMicrotask (console.log.bind (console, ...args));
}
```

Beware of the grouping problem mentioned above.

[image]

Comment: This seems to be a response to a comment on the question. Why not make a separate Q&A?