# How to omit file/line number with console.log

Tags: javascript, browser, google-chrome-devtools, console.log

In the console of Chrome you can write pretty nice stuff these days. Checkout [this](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/tips-and-tricks) link. I've also made a screenshot:

[image]

As you can see in the screenshot too,  the file name / line number (`VM298:4`) is written at the right. Is it possible the remove that, because in my case this is a very long name and more or less breaks the effect I'm trying to make in my console ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is pretty simple to do. You will need to use `setTimeout` with a `console.log.bind`:

```
setTimeout (console.log.bind (console, "This is a sentence."));
```

And if you want to apply CSS or additional text to it just add add `%c` or any other `%` variable:

```
setTimeout (console.log.bind (console, "%cThis is a sentence.", "font-weight: bold;"));
var css = "text-decoration: underline;";
setTimeout (console.log.bind (console, "%cThis is a sentence.", css));
```

Note that this method will always be placed at the end of the log list. For example:

```
console.log ("Log 1");
setTimeout (console.log.bind (console, "This is a sentence."));
console.log ("Log 2");
```

will appear as

```
Log 1
Log 2
This is a sentence.
```

instead of

```
Log 1
This is a sentence.
Log 2
```

I hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 11):

To keep your logging statements clean, you can define `console.print()` as a function and simply use `console.print()` the same as you would use `console.log()` to log without filename/line numbers:

```
// console.print: console.log without filename/line number
console.print = function (...args) {
    queueMicrotask (console.log.bind (console, ...args));
}
```

`console.print` takes the same arguments as `console.log` for example:

`console.print("Text with no filename info.")`

`console.print('%c Custom CSS and no line numbers! ', 'background: #555555; color: #00aaff');`

Comment: Seems it displays logs out of order when nested inside `console.group()`.

Comment: strange, i don't see console.print

Comment: You have to declare the console.print function yourself (using code from code block above) anywhere in a .js file.
Once declared, you can use console.print() the same as you would console.log() and it won't show line numbers.

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to give your source script files shorter names using [sourceURL](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging#source-maps)

```
//# sourceURL=new_file_name.js
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `queueMicrotask` with `console.log.bind` to loose the source file info when logging:

```js
queueMicrotask (console.log.bind (console, "Look! No source file info..."));
```

Queuing microtasks will maintain order of the logging if there are multiple calls, while `setTimeout` is not guaranteed to execute tasks in order.

Comment: FYI setTimeout does guarantee order. It just doesn't guarantee it will be called at the exact _time_.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, sound strange, but none of the above solutions worked for me, and I was in codepen.
but I added these line on top my script plus console.print from answers, and it worked.

```
//# sourceMappingURL-=
//# sourceURL-=
```