# Meaning of yellow background in source tab - Chrome Developer Tools

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

What is the meaning of the yellow background in the sources tab when using Chrome Dev Tools? Normally it's white.

[image: Chrome dev tools sources yellow background]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens when you start editing a source file (notice the star in the other tab, indicating that it's unsaved and the warning icon).

The yellow VM tab shows the unedited source that is currently running.

Answer (score 4):

Yellow background indicates that the script exist only in VM and doesn't have a named corresponding to it in DevTools source editor. It can be an [eval'ed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17367560/chrome-development-tool-vm-file-from-javascript) script or as in your case an old version of the edited script. The old version of the script should be kept after editing because DevTools couldn't update some of the existing functions and they still have to refer to the old source.

DevTools won't allow you to edit source of yellow scripts.

See also this [bug report](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=523436).