# GET http://f.asdfzxcv1312.com/idle.html 503 (Service Unavailable)

Tags: google-chrome, console, google-chrome-devtools

I kept seeing

> GET http://f.asdfzxcv1312.com/idle.html 503 (Service Unavailable)

On my console.

[image]

When I click on the file on the right, I see

[image]

What is that file ? Why do I have it ? How do I get rid of it ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you:

- Tried running in incognito?
- Disabled all extensions?
- Used a clean/new profile?

The `VM{number}` file, is stuff that [isn't attached to a direct script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17373477/2604748). So, there is no context here as to what is happening. We'd need to know an exact site where the problem occurs and know all the scripts running within the page.

Looking at the URL, it looks as if this is running due to an ad service. 503 just means the ad server is having problems, try again later. Right now, the link works fine and doesn't 503. I'm assuming this is just from a script for advertisements and the server providing the ads was having a problem.