# What is the VM prefix in the initiator column in Chrome Dev Tools Network Tab?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, performance-testing, web-performance

In the Chrome Developer Tools Network Tab Initiator Column, sometimes a script has an Initiator which is prefixed with a VM.

My first thoughts are that this stands for Virtual Machine but what do the numbers then stand for?

If I click to view the source, it is still not clear to me what the origin of this script is?

[image: Screenshot of Network Tools from Chrome]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It happens when the JavaScript code does not refer to some normally loaded JS file. For example when the code was executed with "eval". The number has no meaning.

Have a look at [this StackOverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17367560/chrome-development-tool-vm-file-from-javascript) for more information.

Comment: "[VM] (scriptId) has no special meaning. It's a dummy name to help us to distinguish code which are not directly tied to a file name, such as code created using eval and friends."