# JS errors on VM page

Tags: javascript

My web apps is using/starting external JS files for generating common headers/footers. So I don't know these scripts fully. But now I see strange errors which seems to be not connected with my code:

```
VM517:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: XXX_initCore is not defined
    at <anonymous>:1:1
(anonymous) @ VM517:1
```

How to find where is the problem?

Where is the source of the problem?

UPDATE 1:
Generally error appears when application my MVC5 application is started locally. When I open Developer Tools => Network => XHRs; some JS codes are listed, Im analyzing this.

Comment: Is there *any* more context you can give us here…?

Comment: I think might be an error generated by a code supplied by `eval()` execution. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17367560/chrome-development-tool-vm-file-from-javascript

Comment: share your code @P.K.

Comment: I can share, but there is a lot of it, so I try to find root cause