# Chrome Development Tool: inject code into [VM] file

Tags: debugging, google-chrome-devtools

I have been using chrome dev tools for some time and I was used to edit `javascript` files and override functionality of some things as I need.

Recently I learned about `[VM]` files ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17373477/2924323)). But I can't change the script as I did before in normal `js` files. Is there a way to edit that file and put some code there.

Any help..?

Thanks..!!

PS: Currently what I do is add a breakpoint and write my code in the console. This is time consuming and I need to do this every time after the program hit the break point.

Answer (score 0):

I also had a similar problem and I found this that gave this VMxyz a name that you can reference

https://stackoverflow.com/a/18621472/2537641