# Why is the code for the chrome plugin mixed with the content of the AJAX response?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I wrote a image upload with jQuery, the code like this:

[image: code]

After the image is uploaded, it enters the `onComplete` function, but the code throws a exception.The following is the exception:

[image]

And I click the `VM1413:1`, and the following is the code:

`{"msg":"success!","code":0,"data":"a image url"}#yddContainer{display:block;font-family:Microsoft YaHei;position:relative;width:100%;height:100%;top:-4px;left:-4px;font-size:12px;border:1px solid}`

And I find `{"msg":"success!","code":0,"data":"a image url"}`is the ajax response.

And `#yddContainer{display:block;font-family:Microsoft YaHei;position:relative;width:100%;height:100%;top:-4px;left:-4px;font-size:12px;border:1px solid}`, this CSS is for one chrome extension.

So I have some questions:

- Why is the exception code thrown in the VM?
- Why the ajax repsonse appears in the VM?
- Why the chrome extension CSS appears in the VM? And Why they are mixed?

Comment: Probably because the extension intercepts requests and manipulates them …? Adding stuff to HTML resources to show additional content/functionality inside of visited pages would be kinda understandable; but if it does so for other types of resources as well, of course that’s gonna cause trouble. Question remains, whether that is actually the extensions fault - or maybe that of your own system? If it were to respond with JSON data, but does so under a wrong Content-Type, the extension would be rather less at fault.

Comment: @CBroe I think your guess is right, I find the ajax response contentType is `text/html`, maybe the extension add the css to the file if it's `text/html` type. Thank  you much, but I want to know why they are in `VM`, I don't understant the meaning of `VM`.

Comment: See here for what the `VM` thing means: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17373477/1427878

Comment: @CBroe Thanks again.