# Are JQuery event listeners registered within dynamically loaded content containing <script> tags buggy?

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-chrome, event-listener, dynamic-loading

Ok, that is a confusing title. Let's try to break it down.

I have an event listener within $(document).ready, listening on the body for the change of a dropdown and calling a function on change. The update function makes an AJAX call which changes server-side variables, triggering other listeners (which change the page using JS `location.href=...` and will eventually reload the original page after having set up more serverside variables).

Event Listener: `$('body').on('change', '#dropdown', updateFunction);`

This event listener is in a `<script>` tag of HTML content that is dynamically loaded onto the "index" page.

The first time the index page is loaded and the dropdown is used the event listener calls the updateFunction flawlessly, doing its magic, reloading the page, and registering the listener again. Subsequent uses of the dropdown sometimes (very rarely/inconsistently) do its magic, reload the page, but **do NOT register the listener again**...
Using Chrome to inspect the Event Listeners confirms that it doesn't exist, but viewing the source code confirms that the code is identical after a successful load and a subsequent failed reload.

When putting in some `console.log()` statements around the registering of the listener I noticed that if the log statement came from the index page, the listener was correctly registered. When the same log statement came from one of Chrome's VMxxxx page, the listener was not registered and the page failed to function.

In my attempts to resolve this I discovered the following quote:

> Whenever you load HTML content through AJAX, and that content contains  tags, the script will be evaluated using eval() and recognized by Chrome's Sources view as a new file beginning with 'VM'.
>   https://stackoverflow.com/a/23475301/9175117

*This makes me wonder if a JQuery event listener, registered within dynamically loaded content containing a  tag, which is logged in the Chrome console as coming from VMxxxx, is unreliable or buggy.*

Thank you for your patience in making it this far. Can you think of any reason the listener would not be registered a small percentage of the times the page is reloaded through the use of the dropdown?

**UPDATE**
As requested I will try to add an example of what I'm doing. I am sorry that it won't help. "Conjecture" is kind of what I am asking for, and since nobody immediately said "Oh yea, that's buggy" I get the feeling it's not buggy.

I'm working on a ColdFusion site where each page is constructed from pieces of various files depending on dozens of conditions. Most pages are an 'index' containing a 'selectionBar' (of dropdown elements), a div of static content, and a series of divs of dynamic content (sometimes inserted by the server, sometimes inserted after AJAX call returns).

The page in question is roughly:

`index.cfm` // "main" page which includes a layout.cfm of standard HTML and JS libraries, another .cfm for _permissionCheck, another .cfm for the _selectionBar, a div containing another .cfm of the _mainContent, and a  tag listening for "cChanged" which reloads the _mainContent's div, and (if condition is true) reloads the whole index page.

`<cfinclude _selectionBar.cfm>` // Prepares 0-3 dropdown elements, each of which are custom cf_tag elements that have a  tag triggering "xLoaded" when done loading it's contents, "xChanged" when the selected option is changed, and listening for the "xLoaded" of the previous element which indicates reloading is necessary. The first firing "aChanged" on change which reloads the second, which fires "bLoaded" when done loading (which triggers the third to reload) and "bChanged" on change, which (also) reloads the third which fires "cLoaded" when done loading and "cChanged" when it's changed. It's this **cLoaded** that reloads the _mainContent, and the whole page. (not always working as expected)

`<cfinclude _mainContent>` // Includes a handful of other .cfm files, and one main.cfm file (at a time). The main.cfm representing a wizard of sorts, taking you through 1-4 'steps', displaying the next step when you hit the "Next" button (which submits the current step's form, reloads the index.cfm, and displays the next step's form). Each step is another .cfm page with its own  and  tags as well as linked JS files.

Hope that makes the mud a bit more clear.

Comment: Could you please add in simple example of what you mean? It's all conjecture until we know what we're dealing with.

Comment: It's not clear what you're doing. You say you're reloading the page, but you mention loading content using AJAX. Which are you really doing?

Comment: When you use event delegation, the event listener is attached to the `body` element (in this case), not `#dropdown`.

Comment: @Barmar I updated the content hoping to provide more light, but I expect just adding more confusion. My understanding of using Event Delegation like this is that attaching a listener to the body element, which contains the #dropdown element, allows the dropdown to be destroyed and recreated without having to recreate the listener.

I agree with you comment, but I'm not sure that I understand what it is you were trying to warn me of.

Comment: Your update isn't readable because you didn't put backticks around the HTML tags in the text. I started to edit it, but it's too much text. We really need to see actual code, not descriptions, because it's still hard to understand what you're actually doing .