# Unable to save changed code in debugging mode

Tags: debugging, google-chrome-devtools, chromium, developer-tools

I changed some lines of JS code and save in debugging mode. However, when I resume debug system is creating another file with the name as VM3604filename which does not include my changes.

Could anyone please help to resolve?

[image]

Comment: It's a dummy file that Chrome creates if you're changing things and debugging at the same time

Comment: Further reading here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17367560/chrome-development-tool-vm-file-from-javascript

Comment: thanks for the reply, could you plz tell me is if there is any way to edit and debug at the same time . thanks!