# How to debug Javascript on Chrome if the Chrome Debugger keeps wiping the source clean?

Tags: javascript, python, flask, google-chrome-devtools

I'm using Flask to serve a template on Google Cloud Run and that templates has event handlers and scripts which call Ajax back to the Flask server. Lots of opportunities to screw up, but I had it all humming along until a few days ago when I did an upgrade :-(

I know that if I have served broken Javascript (e.g. "False" instead of "false") then it is not uncommon to get not just a console.log flagging the error but also find that the DevTools source tab has the lines are all blank. This is frustrating and the topic of many StackOverflow posts.

My case is slightly different, in that I have no errors flagged in the console, but also no source data. I can put lots of console.log() statements and "infer" that everything apparently working just fine. Except, no source.

Clicking on text of console.log does not bring up the source. Nor does putting "debugger" as the first line of the Javascript. Disabling Cache and refreshing browser do nothing. The behavior repeats if I run Flask on local server vs gunicorn on Cloud Run.

If I render the template to a file and serve that from a dummy Flask template then I see the source code in the debug screen (although no buttons, etc). The source code is about 10MByte and maany Javascript lines were 10,000's of characters per line, so I wrote code to "word-wrap" the HTML down to ~100 characters per line. That exercise was painful, and it didn't help either.

I'm thinking there must be some kind of header that Flask is sending on the "live" dashboard that encourages Chrome to delete the source and it doesn't send same header when I ask it to serve the html read from a file. Is there some documentation on how (and when) the Chrome DevTools gets its javascript from the server?

If I can create a minimal working example I will upload.

Thanks,

Comment: I think my problem may be related to the size of the dashboard. On a smaller file with 1MB of HTML then the debugger doesn't disappear on me. Whereas 10MB trashes it. But something new has appeared..... The webpage itself still has no source, but there is a new entry in the source panel called debugger:///VM98 and it does *have* the source code. Maybe this:: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17367560/chrome-development-tool-vm-file-from-javascript