# How to debug JS of a dynamically loaded page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, browser

I have a page `index.php` that is loading a `test.php` dynamically with javascript into a div element `<div id="overlay_popup"></div>` with :

```
function load_php_content(PHP_PAGE) {
    console.log("load_php_content : "+PHP_PAGE);
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        document.getElementById("overlay_popup").innerHTML = this.responseText;
      }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET",PHP_PAGE ,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

And loaded with for example :

```
load_php_content("test.php?var=1");
```

The page `test.php` contains some React code that appears to be failing. (React elements not showing up.)

**But the page is working perfectly when I load it directly in a page of the browser (Copying the exact url/line sent by php server to the dynamic JS).**

Because it's dynamically generated there is no JS logs for me to figure out where the problem can come from.

1 - If it's possible, do you know where i can read the js "errors/warnings" of this dynamically loaded page ?

2 - Is there something about React that can cause a problem of this type ?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to place this at the top of your JS file, then the file will appear in your dev tools > network. You can then place breakpoints on it and your browser will activate it when the JS is run.

```
//# sourceURL=filename.js
```

It may be an issue with other code though, since as you say, the JS code runs without issues when executed on its own.

[Source for the code snipper above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9092125/how-to-debug-dynamically-loaded-javascript-with-jquery-in-the-browsers-debugg)